# How can I install the latest Image Magick on RedHat Enterprise 6.6?

Tags: redhat, rhel6, imagemagick

I am trying to install the latest ImageMagick (at least 6.8) from the RPM's available [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) on my RedHat Enterprise server

```
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Release:        6.6
Codename:       Santiago
```

where the kernel is

```
2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

but I run into dependency hell, starting with lzma, where I need >5 and RedHat has only 4.999.9.

I've tried adding CentOS and Fedora repositories but if I try to install imageMagick from there - or anything else for that matter, I get a lot of obsoleted packages, error messages and the like, and I fear I might break the whole thing.

Does anyone know of a better way? Am I better off installing from source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Red Hat systems, ImageMagick is available in the default `base` package repository so you only need to run:

```
sudo yum install ImageMagick
```

Note that the package was built with support for X11 and Gtk+ so it has a huge amount of of dependencies – most of which should only be required for a graphical desktop (and ideally shouldn’t be installed on a head-less server).

For RHEL 6, the version of ImageMagick is 6.5.4.7. If you need functionality that is only available in later versions, you’d be better compiling and installing from source; shoe-horning a binary RPM that was compiled for RHEL 5 wouldn’t make sense. Installing from source would also have the benefit that you could customise it by providing appropriate options to its `configure` script during the build process.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of ImageMagick is available in the remi repo. Instructions for how to install Remi are here, http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en

When you have remi configured, you'll need to uninstall your version of imagemagick and install imagemagick-last.

```
yum remove ImageMagick; yum install ImageMagick-last
```

As of today, Base has a package called ImageMagick for which the latest version 6.7.2.7-2. Remi has a package named ImageMagick-last, for which the latest is 6.9.3.10-1 which is the latest version in the 6.x version.

Comment: Notice: you now have "ImageMagick-last" (latest 6.x version, aka 6.9.4-1) and ImageMagick7 (lastest 7.x version, aka 7.0.1-3)